# Hide internal USB device from "Safely remove hardware"

Tags: windows-vista

I have a card reader in my PC (Windows Vista). It is connected to internal USB port, so it never gets disconnected. Since it is USB, device shows up in "Safely Remove Hardware" dialog and explorer context menu.

It is easy to disconnect device by mistake. And then you have to reboot the PC to read another memory card.

Is there a way to tell Windows never to suggest to remove this particular device?

Comment: It can get a lot worse than that: some disk controllers can make **internal hard disks** show as removable devices. Yes, including the disk the O.S. is running on.

Comment: @Massimo Yes, I asked a similar question here: http://superuser.com/questions/12955/how-do-i-remove-the-option-to-eject-sata-drives-from-the-windows-7-tray-icon

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible by default.

[**USB Safely Remove**](http://www.safelyremove.com/) is a program that replaces the built-in feature of Windows and adds several functions, including hiding the devices you don't want to see in the list (see "*Hide device from the tray menu*" in the screenshot below). More explanations about this feature can be found [here](http://www.safelyremove.com/help/ht_hideDevice.htm).

[image]

Comment: Over a decade later and you still can't... classic microsoft