# Is it possible to turn off hot swap feature for HDD drives when using AHCI?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, ahci

I have 3 SATA drives - 1 SSD and 2 common HDDs. After changing HDD controller mode to AHCI and installing Windows 7, I still have choice to safely remove HW devices - disks. Every time I'm going to remove USB flash card I worry that I accidentally turn off system drive (is it even possible?). Is it possible to turn off this feature for those 3 HDDs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove the option to eject SATA drives from the Windows 7 tray icon?](http://superuser.com/questions/12955/how-do-i-remove-the-option-to-eject-sata-drives-from-the-windows-7-tray-icon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30495127/remove-hardware-from-safely-remove-hardware-list.aspx

Not sure if this method can be adapted to non USB devices. Disk drives should show up under 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\IDE
.

> This can be achieved by modifying a registry value. So far
>   I had no time writing a little tool for this...
>
> Devices are shown there if they are marked as removable and
>   if they do no have the 'surprise removal ok' flag. These are
>   bit coded flags:
>
> From cfgmgr32.h:
>
> The device capabilities are found in the registry in a value
>   named 'Capabilities' under (sample for one of my USB flash
>   drives):
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\Vid_058f&Pid_6331\058F091111B
>
> If you take away 4 from the value or add 80h and then
>   refresh the save removal dialog by toggeling the checkbox,
>   then the drive is gone.
>   But the value is reset when you attach the drive for the
>   next time. This is hard coded into the driver and read
>   each time the drive is loaded. If you export the modified
>   value an reg file then you can silently load it on startup
>   by
>   regedit /s hidecardreader.reg
>
> The device id string of your card reader (this
>   Vid_058f&Pid_6331\058F091111B thing) is found in the properties
>   of the USB device in the device manager. My ListUsbDrives
>   tool shows it too (the 'Ctrl  DevID'):
>   http://www.uwe-sieber.de/files/listusbdrives.zip