# How do I enter this into regedit

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, ahci

This post [here](https://superuser.com/a/960793/566428) explains a method for setting a port as internal but I don't understand exactly how to enter it into regedit.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\storahci\Parameters\Device]
"TreatAsInternalPort"=hex(7):30,00,31,00,32,00,33,00,34,00,35,00,00
```

Could anyone advise on how I use this command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a snippet from a `.reg` file. The easiest way to make these registry changes (in this case, adding a value) is to save this as a `.reg` file and open it.

---

1. Copy and paste the code into a text editor, such as `notepad`.

[image]

2. Save the file as a `.reg` file, making sure you choose `All Files` from the `Save as type` drop down:

[image]

3. Double click the file from where you just saved it. You will need to confirm you wish to add this to the registry.

[image]

Upon clicking `Yes`, the changes should be made. You may need to reboot, depending on the changes it makes.

Comment: One can do this manually using regedit by browsing to the *key* `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\storahci\Parameters\Device`, and adding a new *Multi-string value* named "TreatAsInternalPort" then edit it as binary and enter the values listed after "hex(7):" without the commas. Note the hex values listed in the question are "012345" not sure if this is garbage data or what actually needs to be entered

Comment: @Yorik Yes of course, but owing to the fact the key was in hex I didn't want to over-scope the question and this seemed the easier approach. Feel free to add it as another answer though, it's certainly true :)

Comment: No need, consider it an amendment. I agree that the for the majority of cases, the REG file is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you very very much, this has solved my AHCI issue.