# Prevent SD card from being ejected

Tags: windows-10, micro-sd-card, safely-remove-hardware

I have a Chinese tablet that offers Intel Atom x5-z8300 and 64GB internal storage (SanDisk eMMC). It also offers a MicroSD slot. I moved most of my files to the SD card. Now I want to stop it from showing up in "Safely Remove Hardware" menu from the tray icon, preferrably by a registry tweak.

I have tried [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/859886/688600) and created a scheduled task that modifies the correct registry key at system startup, but my SD cars still shows up in the "Safe Remove" menu.

Comment: What about this other answer on that question: https://superuser.com/a/960793/19943

Comment: @Mokubai Looks like the SD card slot has nothing to do with AHCI. No related key is present under `storachi`.