# How do I remove internal SATA disks from the "Safely Remove Hardware" menu?

Tags: windows-7, sata, eject

I have installed Windows 7 (Ultimate) on a PC with an [ASRock 960GM/U3S3 FX](http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/960GMU3S3%20FX/) motherboard, which is an AMD AM3+ motherboard with an AMD 760G/SB710 chipset. Everything installed OK with the latest drivers for all hardware and chipset drivers, but the internal SATA disks appear in the "Safely remove hardware and eject media" menu from the tray icon. I would prefer the internal SATA disk does not appear in this menu as it is not removable and it shows the icon in the notification area of the system tray even when no USB devices are plugged in.

I tried the solution proposed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/12955/how-can-i-remove-the-option-to-eject-sata-drives-from-the-windows-7-tray-icon), but it didn't work.

I did not have high hopes it would work because the SATA controller is configured in IDE mode instead of AHCI mode in the BIOS and the BIOS has no "hot plug" setting for the SATA connectors.

I've seen suggestions to install the latest Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver, but that wouldn't work on an AMD motherboard either.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I wonder who down-voted this question without even writing a comment...

Comment: I didn't, but a good reason to downvote the question is that it asks for help solving a problem without telling us what the problem is. Presumably, the OP thinks that removing internal SATA disks from the menu will solve some problem he has, but we don't know what that problem is.

Comment: I think the problem was clear, internal non-removable drives should not appear in the "Remove hardware" menu. But I edited the question so it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As written [here](http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/960GMU3S3%20FX/index.asp?cat=Specifications) - all your SATA connectors have 'hot plug'. Maybe this option has different name in BIOS?

Also, have you tried [this](http://www.overclock.net/t/974023/fix-ahci-sata-drives-showing-in-safely-remove-hardware) solution?

Quote (solution by `t0adphr0g`):

> This is a Registry fix.
>   You should ALWAYS back up your registry before you make changes - it only takes a second to do it, and if anything happens to it you'll need to reinstall...
>   Here we go...
>
> Regedit your way to:
>   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\msahci**
>   and create a **new KEY** called **"Controller0"**
>   inside **Controller0**, create a new KEY called **"Channel0"**
>   Now inside **"Channel0"**, create a new **DWORD** called **"TreatAsInternalPort"**
>   set this value to **"1"**
>   (this sets SATA port 0 (Drive C) to no longer show up in "Safely Remove Hardware")

You should be able to change "Controller" and "Channel" values to your needs.