# Hard Drives still show up as removable in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, bios

Although this question has been previously asked in this forum, I haven't managed to find a solution for me.

I have two drives (One HDD and One SSD), MB Asus M5A99FX PRO R2.0, and the OS is Windows 10 Pro.

Both drives show up as removable. I have tried to solve the problem edditing "TreatAsInternalDrive" in registry, does not work. Also tried to see what is wrong in the BIOS, trying to deactivate the "Hot Plug" option, but my MB does not allow for that I assume.

Here are some pics of what BIOS and registry look like.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is the same question as [Internal hard drives showing as removable in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1010792)

In this case, editing the registry value does not provide any solution for me.

Comment: What difference does "removable" make? Why is "removable" a problem for you? Compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310).

Comment: I don't want an internal drive to show up as a removable drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internal hard drives showing as removable in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1010792/internal-hard-drives-showing-as-removable-in-windows-10)

Comment: I have tried everything those answers say. But cannot solve it.

Comment: See this page....https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3083627/internal-sata-drives-show-up-as-removeable-media

Comment: Yes, as the post says, I have tried edditing in the registry the "TreatAsInternalPort" value. Still no solution.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by checking how the connections on the motherboard where made.

For anyone having the same problem, before tweaking anything else, I highly recommend you to check your motherboard manual to see if your hard drive is properly connected to the port that the manufacturer recommend you to use.

The trigger to make me check the connection was that the hard drives do not show up in the Bios.

Have a good one.